# How to use xarray.apply_ufunc to apply a function accepting xarray.DataArrays for parallelization using dask?

Tags: python, dask, python-xarray

I have a `xr.DataArray` which I would like to apply a function to in chunks using xarrays using `xr.apply_ufunc` while leveraging built-in support for dask parallelization because my data is too large to fit into memory all at once.
Unfortunately it seems like there is no easy way to have `xr.apply_ufunc` pass `xr.DataArray`s to the function in question.

Below is a minimum working example of what I'm trying to achieve

```py
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr


def my_function(x: xr.DataArray):
    """Compute the DFT of a real-valued signal x"""
    # AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'sample_rate'
    sample_rate = x.sample_rate
    spectrum = xr.apply_ufunc(np.fft.rfft, x, input_core_dims=[["time"]], output_core_dims=[["frequency"]])
    freqs = np.fft.rfftfreq(x.time.size, 1/sample_rate)
    spectrum = spectrum.assign_coords(frequency=freqs)
    return spectrum

# create random data for demo purposes, in reality I'm loading data from disk
# time_domain = xr.open_dataset("timedomain.nc", chunks=dict(time=1000))
rng = np.random.default_rng()
time_domain = xr.DataArray(rng.multivariate_normal(np.zeros(3), cov=np.diag(np.ones(3)), size=1000000), dims=["time", "a"]).chunk(time=1000)
time_domain.attrs["sample_rate"] = 1000

# determine core-dims automatically (I want map blocks along the time domain)
core_dims = [dim for dim in time_domain.dims if dim != "time"]

spectrum = xr.apply_ufunc(
    my_function,
    time_domain,
    input_core_dims=[core_dims],
    output_core_dims=[core_dims],
    dask="parallelized",
    output_dtypes=[complex])

spectrum.compute()
```

Unfortunately `my_function` gets passed a `numpy.ndarray` when using `dask='parallelized'`. I thought that  maybe switching to `dask='allowed'` may work, but then the dask array gets passed to my function directly, which also throws a similar error (dask array has no attribute `sample_rate`).

Is there a straight-forward way of making arbitrary functions that accept `xr.DataArray` work with `dask='parallelized'` or do I have to refactor my entire code base to support this pattern?